# Spring MVC @RequestParams

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is the url :
https://192.168.33.10/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/bahmnicore/bahmniencounter/search?includeAll=false&patientUuid=210d0739-7937-4fb7-8f53-752f393cb4b7&visitUuid=c1c26908-3f10-11e4-adec-0800271c1b75

It is landed into Spring MVC's below controller method -

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "search")
@ResponseBody
public List<BahmniDiagnosisRequest> search(@RequestParam("patientUuid") String patientUuid, @RequestParam(value = "fromDate", required = false) String date, String visitUuid) throws Exception {
    if (visitUuid != null) {
        return bahmniDiagnosisService.getBahmniDiagnosisByPatientAndVisit(patientUuid, visitUuid);
    } else {
        return bahmniDiagnosisService.getBahmniDiagnosisByPatientAndDate(patientUuid, date);
    }
}
```

If you see the spring annotation `@Request` Params is not present for the `visitUuid` parameter.

The code above used to work even though the parameter was not present. But recently it throws an Exception, there is no request parameter for `visitUuid`.
Solution is simple if I add `@RequestParams("visitUuid")` it works.

But my question is can parameter in a GET request get mapped to appropriate variables on the Controller code even if we don't have a `@RequestParamter` mapping.

Comment: Yes BUT only when the compiler compiles with debug information, else it will not work. With debug information the parameter names are preserved else they are optimized and will not match any more. Generally it is better to simply add `@RequestParam` even if it would be only for documentation purposes.

Comment: @M.Deinum Debug symbols mean you can omit the name, not that you can omit the annotation entirely.

Comment: But the code was actually woking without the Spring annotation. It only starts failing now. Also this thing is working in other machines without the annotation.

Comment: This is another example of a controller :     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/active")
    @ResponseBody
    public BahmniEncounterTransaction getActive(ActiveEncounterParameters activeEncounterParameters) {
        EncounterTransaction activeEncounter = emrEncounterService.getActiveEncounter(activeEncounterParameters);
        return bahmniEncounterTransactionMapper.map(activeEncounter, activeEncounterParameters.getIncludeAll());
    }
Here also it works without Spring annotation.

Comment: @chrylis that depends the older infrastructure the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` did work without the annotation the newer infrastructure `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` requires the annotation. So if they changed the configuration or upgraded spring versions it might have changed.

Answer (score 0):

No, the appropriate mapping annotation (`@RequestParam`, `@PathVariable`, `@ModelAttribute`, or `@RequestBody`) is required. The *name* of the parameter can be omitted if you compile with debug symbols (which is the usual default), but you have to tell Spring where to look for the value.

Note also that Spring has an impressive type-conversion system, and if your service is capable of (or can be refactored to) taking a `UUID` parameter instead of a `String`, you can use `@RequestParameter UUID patientUuid`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below either options

```
@RequestParams(value = "visitUuid" ,  defaultValue = "yourDefaultValue")

//Or

@RequestParams(value = "visitUuid" ,  required=false)
```